# Javascript appears not to be running

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Im just trying to build a basic site for linking tenants and properties, and I am coming into some issues with a collapsible web grid. This javascript comes from a tutorial, have repurposed it to fit my task. The issue is my javascript simply doesnt seem to be running. Find below my cshtml and also my shared layout.

**Cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<HousingProject.Models.Property>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canSort: false);
}
<style type="text/css">
    th, td {
        padding: 5px;
    }

    th {
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    }

    #gridT, #gridT tr {
        border: 1px solid #0D857B;
    }

    #subT, #subT tr {
        border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    }

    #subT {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 95%;
    }

        #subT th {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

    .hoverEff {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .hoverEff:hover {
            background-color: rgb(248, 242, 242);
        }

    .expand {
        background-image: url(/Content/themes/base/images/pm.png);
        background-position: -22px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .collapse {
        background-image: url(/Content/themes/base/images/pm.png);
        background-position: -2px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Property", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("filter")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HouseNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StreetName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Town)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Postcode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MaxOccupancy)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HouseNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StreetName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Town)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Postcode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MaxOccupancy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div id="main" style="padding:25px; background-color:white;">
    @grid.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new { id = "gridT", width = "700px" },
columns: grid.Columns(
grid.Column("HouseNumber", "House Number"),
grid.Column("StreetName","Street Name"),
grid.Column("Town", "Town"),
grid.Column("City", "City"),
grid.Column("Postcode", "Postcode"),
grid.Column("MaxOccupancy", "Max Occupancy"),
grid.Column("CurrentOccupancy", "Current Occupancy"),
grid.Column(format: (item) =>
{
    WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.CurrentTenants);
    return subGrid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "subT" },
    columns: subGrid.Columns(
    subGrid.Column("FirstName", "First Name"),
    subGrid.Column("Surname", "Surname"),
    subGrid.Column("Age", "Age"),
    subGrid.Column("Employer", "Employer")
    )
    );
})
)
 )
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var size = $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").size(); // get total column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").last().remove(); // remove last column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr").prepend("<th></th>"); // add one column at first for collapsible column
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).prepend(
                    $("<td></td>")
                    .addClass("expand")
                    .addClass("hoverEff")
                    .attr('title', "click for show/hide")
                    //.attr('onclick', 'toggleWebGrid()')
                );
            //Now get sub table from last column and add this to the next new added row
            var table = $("table", this).parent().html();
            //add new row with this subtable
            $(this).after("<tr><td></td><td style='padding:5px; margin:0px;' colspan='" + (size - 1) + "'>" + table + "</td></tr>");
            $("table", this).parent().remove();
        });

        //by default make all subgrid in collapse mode
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr td.expand").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
        });

    });
    //toggle expand and collapse
    $(function () {
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr td.collapse").on('click', function () {
            alert('test');
            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Shared Layout**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Properties","Index","Property")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Im sure you guys will figure it out, been banging my head for a while now, cant even get the debugger to step into it so I'm sure its something wrong in config not the javascript. Please note the tabled part of the page is simply a legacy thing, I dont desperately want to remove it untill this new webgrid works. Ta.

Comment: Do you see any error con the browser console?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "which is in relation to an image, shouldnt be an issue, and also 

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" which im pretty sure is the issue, on line 219, which is the document ready call.

Comment: Sounds like your page didn't load jquery to me

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to move the

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

to head section of the sharedLayout. No idea why MVC defaults them to being at the bottom. Seems unhelpful.

Comment: Whats wrong with having the scripts at the bottom? Your problem is that you script is not inside the `@section Scripts { your scripts here }`